# Nintendo DS emulator for Mac with more than 2x speed?

Tags: osx, game, macos, emulator

I am currently using DeSmuME, and it can only be sped up to 2x.

[image]

Is there any DS emulator for Mac that can do faster than 2x? My hardware can handle it.